# make a dashboard to has to make similar query too many times and performance bad

Tags: postgresql

I have a question here. we have a customer list and product list and sale table. We want to show each customer to buy each product's total sale.
so I use the query like following:

```
select ...
from ...
where customer="" and product="".
```

the query is standard simple one. but the table/dashboard is 20*10. It means for each customer and product pair i have to run a query. i have to run query 200 times. which is super slow.
how to improve this? thanks
right now the dashboard give me 20 customer and 10 product and then i go to database for 200 times. it is from a customer list to pick first 20 and another 20 like this way. the product is the same way to choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by ... Something like

Select customer, product, sum(sales) -- or whatever you need 
From ...
Group by customer, product

The server would do the aggregation, and the query is much faster than doing 200 queries

Comment: I have some materials on SQL aggregates at https://github.com/okaram/DBMaterials/blob/master/StudyNotes/Ch10-SQL-DML/6_SQL_Aggregates.pdf

Comment: hi, right now the dashboard give me 20 customer and 10 product and then i go to database for 200 times. it is not random customer to pick. it is from a customer list to pick first 20 and another 20 like this way.

Comment: You can store the 20 customers in another table, and use a join or IN to only get those customers (and same with products). If you're generating them, you can use the same query and an IN clause to get only those you want.